# How do I call the fully qualified Devise sign_in method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How do I explicitely call Devise sign_in? I already have a method in my controller called `sign_in`.

I tried

```
require 'devise/controllers/sign_in_out'
  Devise::Controllers::SignInOut.sign_in @user

cannot load such file -- devise/controllers/sign_in_out
```

and

```
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  Devise::Controllers::Helpers.sign_in @user

undefined method `sign_in' for Devise::Controllers::Helpers:Module
```

but neither worked.

I also tried

```
alias_method :devise_sign_in, :sign_in # keep hold of the Devise sign_in method before we overwrite it.
  devise_sign_in @user
```

which worked in the browser but when I ran `rspec` it gave this error:

> /rsync/BK-Development/app/controllers/community_members_controller.rb:5:in `alias_method': undefined method`sign_in' for class `CommunityMembersController' (NameError)
>               from /rsync/BK-Development/app/controllers/community_members_controller.rb:5:in`'

I found the source of the method here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v2.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

Devise version 2.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it to work with

```
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
alias_method :devise_sign_in, :sign_in # keep hold of the Devise sign_in method before we overwrite it.
...
  devise_sign_in @user
```

I'd still like to know how to call a method directly. In Java, you can call any method by specifying the full package and method. There should be a way to do that in Ruby too.

Comment: Amazingly there isn't... you might try `Class.new.extend(Devise::Controllers::Helpers).sign_in(user)`

Comment: Neither of these worked for me, but the controller is in an engine.  Exactlly where in the controller should these lines go and just what is the trigger for overloading?

Comment: Amazing, I've been looking for this for years. 

Comment: @Obromios this definitely does work. In my case I don't need to alias it, just include the Helpers & attr_reader :session, :request.